# Behavoiur of global in nested functions in Python

Tags: python-3.x, scope, global-variables

```
def f():
    x=42
    def g():
        global x
        x=43
    print("Before calling g:",x)
    print("Calling g now")
    g()
    print("After calling g:",x)
f()
print("x in main:",x)
```

Output :

```
Before calling g: 42
Calling g now 
After calling g: 42
x in main: 43
```

My question is inspite of declaring x as global, why after calling g() x=42?.Since x is declared global python should maintain a single copy of x. Is'nt it?

Comment: `global` declarations are local. A `global` declaration in one function is local to that function.

Answer (score 2):

In function `g()` you are declaring variable `x` global. That variable doesn't exists yet in global namespace so when assigning `43` to it, the python creates it in `globals()`.

Note:
Variable `x` in function `f()` isn't global, it exists in local namespace of that function.

To access variable `x` declared in function `f()` from function `g()`, declare variable `x` in function `g()` `nonlocal`.

EDIT:

**Example 1:** x is defined globally and also locally inside f()

```
x = 43
def f():
    x=42
    print(x)
f()         # prints 42
print(x)    # prints 43
```

**Example 2:** x isn't defined globally, but inside function f() the x is defined `global`. That means when assigning to x inside function f(), Python will make the variable inside global namespace and you can print it outside function `f()` too:

```
def f():
    global x
    x=42
    print(x)
f()         # prints 42
print(x)    # prints 42
```

Comment: so  print("After calling g:",x)  should print 43 instead, because x is now declared global and should maintain single value

Comment: @ShubhamS.Naik No, because in function f() the variable x isn't global. If you put `global x` into function f(), then yes, function f() will change it globally.

Answer (score 1):

A global variable is a module-level variable. Your variable `x` is in the scope of the function `f()` and is therefore not a global variable. Define `x` at the module level and your code would work as intended:

```
x = 42
def f():
    def g():
        global x
        x=43
    print("Before calling g:",x)
    print("Calling g now")
    g()
    print("After calling g:",x)
f()
```

This outputs:

```
Before calling g: 42
Calling g now
After calling g: 43
```